# Очень долго считываются слова с Word-документа, C#

Tags: c#, ms-word

Есть такой код, который считывает данные с Word-документа:

```
public void getWordTokens(string wordFilePath)
    {
        Object fileName = wordFilePath;
        Word.Application app = new Word.Application();

        var _tokenList = new List<string>();
        try
        {
            app.Documents.Open(ref fileName);
            Word.Document document = app.ActiveDocument;
            Console.WriteLine("Words count - " + document.Words.Count);
            Console.WriteLine("Document name - " + document.Name);
            StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 1; i < document.Words.Count; i++)
            {
                res.Append(document.Words[i].Text);
            }
Console.WriteLine(res.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            app.Quit();
        }
    }
```

Вопросов в работе нет, на очень небольших вордовских-файлах работает относительно быстро (на самом деле нет, но терпимо). Но на больших файлах - начинается кошмар - работает слиииишком долго.

Как можно это все дело улучшить?

P.S. при экстренном закрытии работающей программы, процесс Word'a не закрывается, хотя окружен в *finnaly*, это норма?

Comment: А что есть экстренное закрытие? Через диспетчер задач?

Comment: @VladD да, или диспетчер задач, или в отладчике закрытие. Соль в том, что большой документ этот код обрабатывал бы очень долго (больше 10 мин. точно, на дольше меня не хватало)

Comment: А, ну тогда норма. Жёсткое убийство процесса не даёт ему возможности выполнить блок `finally`. Процесс убивается вотпрямща.

Comment: @VladD спасибо, а можете что-то подсказать по основному вопросу? Возможно есть какой-то другой вариант получить весь текст?

Comment: К сожалению, не имел никаких дел с Word'ом, сорри. В качестве варианта, может быть, уменьшить количество обращений? Попробовать получить весь текст одним махом, и самостоятельно выделить из него слова?

Comment: @VladD я тоже думал об этом, но документация по этому COM-интерфейсу крайне невнятная и скупая, как это сделать - не имею понятия.

Comment: Вот вроде есть по абзацам: http://mantascode.com/c-how-to-parse-the-text-content-from-microsoft-word-document/

Comment: @VladD да, действительно, работает в десятки раз быстрее, документ на ~9.5к слов считался за минуту (по словам - больше 10 мин, дальше я выключал).

Comment: Ага, это уже лучше. Надо глянуть, нету ли где-то вообще всего текста.

Comment: [Вот тут](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1011234/276994) ещё есть что-то, но там вроде другой подход.

Comment: @VladD да, там через Open XML SDK, но оно и работает только для *.docx файлов, но, т.к. в нашем универе активно используются *.doc стандарт, он мне, к сожалению, не подходит =\\

Answer (score 3, accepted):

не надо циклов. текст документа можно получит сразу

```
    private string GrabWordFileWords(string file_name)
    {
        string result = null;

        // открыть файл
        object filename = file_name;
        object confirm_conversions = false;
        object read_only = true;
        object add_to_recent_files = false;
        object format = 0;
        object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        try
        {
            WordApp._Document word_doc =
                _word_app.Documents.Open(ref filename, ref confirm_conversions,
                    ref read_only, ref add_to_recent_files,
                    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                    ref missing, ref format, ref missing, ref missing,
                    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

            // получить текст из файла
            result = word_doc.Content.Text;

            object save_changes = false;
            word_doc.Close(ref save_changes, ref missing, ref missing);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно все сделать значительно более быстрым, если не использовать interop.

С вордом не работал... Но на вскидку предложу 2 более быстрых пути:

1. Использовать OpenXML библиотеку.(в твоем случае нужно конвертировать перед этим док в докх) (OpenXML достаточно НЕ интуитивна, потому можешь поискать обертку вокруг нее что бы можно было работать проще. Для ексель файлов это ClosedXML, вполне возможно что для вордовских какая другая, не в курсе)
2. ты можешь пересохранить doc в docx c .XML расширением и через regex спарсить нужные данные. Не лучшая идея, зато значительно быстрее interop

в обоих случаях документ практически любого размера будет спарсен в доли секунды.

Comment: [Регулярка?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/276994)

Comment: для большинства случаев вполне подойдет. А часных случаев как там показано не так уж много)

Comment: Лучше не заглядывать внутрь архива docx. Там ад :)